# WHERE - Display value in Column1 only if matches value in Column2

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns of date/time data, from one table. Column1 has multiple values and is the only one displayed in the query. Column2 will only have one date/time value that matches the most recent value from Column1. I'm only interested in displaying that matched value, in Column1.

```
Column1
2014-03-08 00:00:00.000
2014-03-08 00:00:00.000
2014-03-08 09:03:00.000
2014-03-10 01:58:00.000

Column2
2014-03-10 01:58:00.000
```

The data/time value varies day to day so I can't actually write a where statement based on a specific time stamp. I just the most recent value in Column1 to display if it matches the other in Column2. So conventional thinking would be:

```
WHERE Column1 = 'Column2' 
or
WHERE Column1 >= 'Column2' <-- since it will never be greater
```

I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

.
Both values are yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:ms format.

Comment: Remove the '' from column2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t1.column1 from table1 t1
inner join table1 t2 on t1.Column1 = t2.Column2
```

for the `where column1 = column2` to work, the values has to be in the same row. This query does not assume that.

You could also do:

```
select column1 from table1 
where column1 in (select column2 from table1)
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e591c/7)

Answer (score 0):

remove quotes:

```
 WHERE Column1 = Column2
```

or

```
 WHERE Column1 >= Column2
```